# Docker, CodeIgniter, phpunit & Github action : Cache unable to write to "/var/www/html/writable/cache/"

Tags: docker, codeigniter, docker-compose, github-actions, phpunit

When I run docker `exec api-php8 php vendor/bin/phpunit` to execute my tests.

During local development, the tests work fine!
However, when I run this command in a GitHub action to create a workflow, the tests run, but all of them encounter the same error:

> CodeIgniter\Cache\Exceptions\CacheException: Cache unable to write to "/var/www/html/writable/cache/"

I've tried several solutions in my Dockerfile:

```
RUN chmod g+w /var/www/

RUN usermod -u 1000 www-data

RUN usermod -u 1000 root

RUN chmod -R 755 /var/www/

RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/

RUN chown -R root /var/www/
```

This is my first project with Docker, and I'm working on it alone, so it's a bit difficult. If you have any solutions, I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: Do you share or copy files locally between the Docker image (guest) and your computer (host)?

Comment: Do it a second time, but from scratch. Only add lines to the Dockerfile you know what you are adding it for. If the source you copied it from you don't understand, use AI to have it explained to you, then also use the documentation and read about each directive, and for RUN use manpages to understand the commands. In the current form of your question it is not clear what you consider a solution, and what you expected per each solution nor how you verified that your expectations are met.